# Downloading HTML Table into MS Access

Tags: php, html, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to import the table from the following link into my database:
http://www.abif.cl/tasas.php?tipo=5

I'm trying to do this by downloading the page as an HTML file into a directory through VBA, then creating a linked table.

This works perfectly fine when I download it manually through Chrome, using the "Download Complete Webpage" option under "Save As".

However, when I download the webpage using VBA, I get Reserved Error (-5016) when I try to link the table.

**Clarification: The error does not occur when I try downloading the page as HTML; rather, it happens after I try to link a table to the downloaded HTML (does not occur if HTML was downloaded manually through browser)**

Here is the VBA I'm using to download the HTML:

```
Option Compare Database

Option Explicit

Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" ( _
    ByVal pCaller As Long, _
    ByVal szURL As String, _
    ByVal szFileName As String, _
    ByVal dwReserved As Long, _
    ByVal lpfnCB As Long) _
    As Long

Public Function DownloadFile( _
    ByVal strURL As String, _
    ByVal strLocalFilename As String) _
    As Long

    Dim lngRetVal As Long

    lngRetVal = URLDownloadToFile(0, strURL & vbNullChar, strLocalFilename & vbNullChar, 0, 0)

    DownloadFile = lngRetVal

End Function
```

Please let me know if there's any other information I could provide!
Perhaps there's a way of downloading the "Complete Webpage" in VBA?

Thanks!

Comment: The download works (the & vbnullchar is redundant btw) you should edit and show where the error occurs

Comment: @AlexK. I've had no problems with the download - when I try to link my database to the downloaded HTML, I get the error

Comment: Related to this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30673263/html-ms-access-import-error)

Comment: @Gustav I asked that question too; they are separate because the errors are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried downloading the HTML this way and it happened to work. This is by no means an elegant solution and I'm still open to any suggestions as to why I was getting my error / how to fix it. Thanks.

```
Public Function SaveHTML(strURL As String, strOutFile As String)

Dim IE As Object
Dim i As Long
Dim FF As Integer


Set IE = CreateObject("Internetexplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = False
IE.Navigate strURL
Do
Loop While IE.Busy

'Creates a file as specified
' this will overwrite an existing file if already exists
CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile strOutFile

FF = FreeFile
Open strOutFile For Output As #FF

With IE.Document.Body
    Print #FF, .OuterHtml & .InnerHtml
End With

Close #FF

IE.Quit
'Set IE = Nothing

End Function
```